In the Spring framework, what are the differences in the loading order between the @Controller and @Component annotations?
Why is it that in classes annotated with @Controller, objects can be automatically wired using the @Autowired annotation, whereas in classes annotated with @Component, automatic
example:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;
}

the testService!=null,successfully autowired.
but,
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestServer {

 private static TestService testService;

 @Autowired
    public void setTestService(TestService  testService) {
        TestServer.testService= testService;
    }
}

If i take the same way to autowire testService which is defined in the TestController,
unfortunately failed,and testService=null,
so,what's the difference between the @Component and @Controller?
add:
If I use the same definition method as the first example, I will get a null pointer exception. The second example is the solution. I'm just a little confused why this is the case. Is the class decorated with @Componet loaded earlier?

Autowiring should work in this case as far as I'm aware. Is Spring correctly detecting TestServer as a Bean? How are you using it?

Why your TestService field is static? Maybe that's your problem - you won't be able to access it from a static context.

There is no difference, @Controller is just a specialized @Component. Another thing is that an autowired field/value cannot by null in Spring, your application would blow up. So if it is you are doing things in a different way then shown here.
